# Call events delayed with all its arguments

Tags: extjs, extjs4, task, delay

I want to collect a bunch of events in a defined timeframe. I thought about using Ext.util.DelayedTask like

```
var task = new Ext.util.DelayedTask(function(a,b) { console.log(a,b) }, this),
    handler = function(a,b) { task.delay(500); };

ref.on({
    eventA: handler,
    eventB: handler,
    scope: this
});
```

But that seems not to work because the arguments are undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply the arguments here. Try this

```
handler = function(a,b) { task.delay(500, null, null, arguments); };
```